# Positioning form elements and their labels in row

Tags: html, css, css-float

How to position input form elements with their labels like this but not using table? Labels should be centered above input elements and blocks in row should be centered within outer block.

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|       label1       label2       label3       |
|    [..........] [..........] [..........]    |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

There could be 1, 2, 3 or more elements in the same row.

I tried this:

```css
    .outer{text-align:center;}
    .inner{float:left;}
```

```html
    <form>
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
          <label for="l1">label1</label><br><input id="l1" name="label1">
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
          <label for="l2">label2</label><br><input id="l2" name="label2">
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
          <label for="l3">label3</label><br><input id="l3" name="label3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: could you at least post a HTML structure ?

Comment: As @Paulie_D notification its necessary to place your tried out code.. and do some research on that..., Hence that will get you an experience of learning something new.. Thanks!

Comment: Come on guys, I spent an hour trying to force floating block, sometimes label are centerd and cannot center blocks in outer block, sometimes something else. So I tried to find help here because I know that someone dealing with this CSS can solve this in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place them in the same div, and center the text in that div:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align:center;
}

.wrapper * {
  text-align:left;
}

.okay {
  display:inline-block;
}

.okay p {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="okay">
  <p>text</p>
  <input type='text'>
 </div>
 <div class="okay">
  <p>text</p>
  <input type='text'>
 </div>
 <div class="okay">
  <p>text</p>
  <input type='text'>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sbrbot Now it is. Center the elements in your parent, then align left in the child element. In this case body is the parent, but you can use every element instead.

Comment: These three inner blocks here are not centered inside outer one, that's what I'd like to acieve.

Comment: That's it now. BTW what BODY * (this asterisk) mean?

Comment: That means wildcard. Every element inside the body element is caught by *.

Comment: This wrapper, that's it. Tha't exactly that I wanted to kindly ask of you. Thanks.

Comment: As fa as I can see this .wrapper * (with asterisk) is not needed at all. Give no effect.

Comment: Not in this example but if you add More elemens in the wrapper that prevents text align Center.

Answer (score 1):

Its also possible through bootstrap framework also.. which makes responsive

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="label1">label</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="label1" placeholder="labeltext">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="label2">label</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="label2" placeholder="labeltext">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="label2">label</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="label2" placeholder="labeltext">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```